# ntheorem: theoremclass not working?

Tags: ntheorem

I try to use the `ntheorem` package, but for some reason I don't understand, the `\theoremclass` commands seems to just being ignored. This is my MWE, or rather, MNWE ;)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\renewcommand{\qed}{$\hfill\square$}

\begin{document}

%% Theorem-Umgebungen
\newtheorem{theorems}{}
\theoremclass{changebreak}
\theoremindent0cm
\newtheorem{sentence}[theorems]{Satz}

\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorems]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorems]{Anmerkung}

\theoremclass{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theoremnumbering{none}
\theoremsymbol{\qed}
\newtheorem{proof}[theorems]{Beweis}


\begin{sentence}[Ein Beispielsatz]
Sei $X$ gegeben, dann folgt $Y$.
\end{sentence}
\begin{proof}
Hier steht der Beweis des Satzes.
\end{proof}

\begin{definition}[Eine Beispieldefinition]
$X$ nennen wir $Y$, falls $X=Y$ gilt.
\end{definition}

\begin{remark}[Eine Beispielbemerkung]
$X$ hat eine Eigenschaft.
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

This code produces the following output:[image: output]

So, the numbers are not swapped, there are no breaks and the proof section still has got a number. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Your use of `\theoremclass` is wrong. If you have already defined some theorem-like environment, say called `example`, then `\theoremclass{example}` will set the various parameters to the same values as they were for `example` such that subsequent `\newtheorem`s look the same as `example`.  Use `\theoremstyle{changebreak}` to use the style `changebreak` (note the use of `style` instead of `class`).